# (Swift) Tableview cell: textLabel showing up, but detailTextLabel isn't

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I set up a table view in storyboard and gave it a custom cell class:

Storyboard:

[image]

Cell class:

```
class CommentCell: UITableViewCell {

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    textLabel?.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: textLabel!.frame.origin.y - 2, width: textLabel!.frame.width, height: textLabel!.frame.height)
    detailTextLabel?.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: detailTextLabel!.frame.origin.y + 2, width: detailTextLabel!.frame.width, height: detailTextLabel!.frame.height)
}

let logoView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 24
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    return imageView
}()

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    addSubview(logoView)
    logoView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    logoView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    logoView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 48).isActive = true
    logoView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 48).isActive = true
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

}
```

And then in my view controller I gave it some dummy text to test it out, and the textLabel text shows up fine, but the detailTextLabel text and the imageView do not.

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
let commentors = ["Person One", "Person Two", "Person Three"]
let comments = ["Comment One", "Comment Two", "Comment Three"]


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CommentCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = commentors[indexPath.row]
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = comments[indexPath.row]
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        cell.logoView.image = UIImage(named: "testImage")
    }

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return commentors.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 72
}
```

This is what I see when I run the app:

[image]

Anyone know why the textLabel is showing up but not the detailTextLabel or the image?

Comment: I guess your both the labels are not showing up as you have not added them on the views.Table view has default label property cell.textLabel?.text . So that is not your created label . You need to add your labels on  cell.I am just not sure about it i have not tested your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A table view cell with style `custom` has no implicit `detailTextLabel` and no `imageView`.

You have to implement the elements in the storyboard and connect them to appropriate `IBOutlet`s.

Comment: Ok thanks, I ended up doing that. Was just tying to see if it could work programatically.

Answer (score 0):

@vadian's answer is correct, however, you do not have to add the other label manually.
I was facing the same issue and realised while looking at your question that the type of the cell in the Interface Builder is `Custom` and not `subtitle`. You initialise it correctly, but it seems like the style set in the IB has priority.
`subtitle` style makes sure that the `detailTextLabel` shows up and shows it already in the storyboard.

Hope this helps others.